# Watir Webdriver: testing that clicking outside a modal does not close it

Tags: cucumber, automated-tests, watir-webdriver

Let's say I have a modal.

`@my_modal = @brower.div(id: 'TheModal')`

Let's say I have a test that brings up the modal (cucumber in this example)

```
 Given I ...
 When I ...
 Then "My Modal" is visible
 When I click outside the modal
 Then "My Modal" is visible
```

Now to define the step to click outside the modal:

```
 When /^I click outside the modal$/ do
   # what do I put here?
 end
```

Any ideas?

I just tried `@browser.element(xpath: '//html').click` based on [How to simulate mouse click on blank area in website by Selenium IDE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27966080/how-to-simulate-mouse-click-on-blank-area-in-website-by-selenium-ide). I got the error `Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError: unknown error: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Watir only allows you to click on elements that are visible. For most modal implementations, only elements inside the modal would be considered visible.

Try: `@browser.element.wd.click`

It could help to share the html if that does not work.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up with this `@browser.driver.action.move_to(@browser.div(id: 'js-overlay').wd, 0, 0).click.perform`.

There was a div in the background that dimmed everything, `div#js-overlay`. clicking on it normally with `@browser.div(id: 'js-overlay') didn't work b/c it clicked right in the middle where the modal was, so that's why there is that extra business for clicking the top left of that particular div (thanks to Justin Ko!).

Comment: kudos for sharing the solution you came up with, I doubt you will be the only person that needs to do this sort of thing (or the reverse, that clicking outside the modal closes it, another common paradigm for advisory modals)